# PHP MySQL - Specify vehicle state of tracking by speed , MOVE STOP START

Tags: php, mysql

below is `data` table :

```
/* TableName:Data */
  id  |  speed
----------------
   1  |   3
   2  |   0
   3  |   0
   4  |   5
   5  |   6
   6  |   7
   7  |   0
   8  |   0
   9  |   0
  10  |   3
   N  |   2
```

I want to have a result (with out repeat zero speed) , and specify state of moving ; ***example :***

if first speed row is zero `Remove it from result` else show with `state=START/MOVE`
if speed is zero on first row after move state then set `state=STOP`
if speed is repeat with zero value `Remove it from result`
after zero value of speed if speed not zero then set `state=START`

***Example Results:***

```
      /* Results */
  id  |  speed  | status
-------------------------
   1  |   3     |  START/MOVE
   2  |   0     |  STOP
   4  |   5     |  START
   5  |   6     |  MOVE
   6  |   7     |  MOVE
   7  |   0     |  STOP
  10  |   3     |  START
   N  |   2     |  MOVE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT     a.*, 
           CASE WHEN @val IS NULL THEN @val:='START/MOVE'
                WHEN speed = 0 AND @val IN ('START/MOVE', 'START', 'MOVE') THEN @val:='STOP'
                WHEN speed > 0 AND @val = 'STOP' THEN @val:='START'
                WHEN speed > 0 AND @val IN ('START', 'MOVE') THEN @val:='MOVE'
           END AS status
FROM       (
           SELECT    a.*
           FROM      data a 
           LEFT JOIN (
                     SELECT MIN(id)-1 AS id, 0 AS speed
                     FROM   data 

                     UNION ALL

                     SELECT id, speed
                     FROM   data 
                     ) b ON a.id = b.id + 1 AND (a.speed,b.speed) IN ((0,0))
           WHERE     b.id IS NULL
           ) a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @val:=NULL) val_init
```

Tested and working.

I'd show a SQLFiddle Demo, but unfortunately, their site is down at the moment.